# Solving the initial value problem as a vector function r(t) from t

Tags: vectors, initial-value-problems

Consider the differential equation
$$
\frac{d \textbf{r}}{dt}=(t^3+4t)\,\vec i + t \vec j, \qquad
\textbf{r}(0)= \vec i+ \vec j
$$

I got
$$\textbf{r}(t) = (\frac{t^4}{4}+ 2t^2) \vec i + \frac{t^2}{2} \vec j.$$
What's the next step? What to do with $\textbf{r}(0)=\vec i+ \vec j$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a problem in the 3d physical space. If this is the case, you cannot in general neglect the $\vec k$ component. The general solution would then be

$$r(t) = \left(\frac 14 t^4 + 2t^2 + c_1\right) \vec i + \left(\frac 12 t^2+ c_2\right) \vec j  + c_3 \vec k$$

The initial condition $r(0)= \vec i + \vec j$ means that when $t=0$ the $\vec i$ and $\vec j$ components evaluate to 1 and the $\vec k$ component evaluates to zero. Taking this into consideration, you know that $c_1=c_2 = 1$ and $c_3=0$.

Comment: The solution is right. However, you get the same answer if you restrict yourself to 2d space. The important part is to get the integration constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: @Andrei You are correct, with this initial condition the solution remains in the $xy$-plane.